# Use an html value into React component

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Another developer created an html webpage with entries like:

```
<div id='username'>usernameValue</div>
<div id='reactCompIdPlace'/>
```

From that page I need to get the usernameValue value and pass it to a react component as a props and using jsx. This react component will be placed at the second

```
  <div id='reactCompIdPlace'/>
```

Is this possible? How? Thanks

Comment: use querySelector?

Comment: Your question is not all that clear. When you say "another developer created a webpage..." do you mean that you have an existing react application that you need to incorporate this page into? Where is your app rendered? When you say, "the react component will be placed at the second div..." Do you mean this is where your main virtual DOM rendering occurs? The "React" way to do what you're after would be to create a component from what the "other developer" has created and only have a single entry div for your react render.

Comment: I wish all could be 100% react but live is not like that. The other developer created a page that I must use as a source of some info for a React component. For example, this page could be created through a Scala/Java program and now it could be needed to enhance that html view with react. This is the reason of my question. I visited the React tutorial and I couldn't find an easy example to this question.

Answer (score 2):

In your main component you can query the DOM

```
const username = document.getElementById('username'). textContent;
```

And then pass it to the component that need that value, something like this

```
class App extends Component{
  state = {username: ''};

  componentDidMount(){
    const username = document.getElementById('username'). textContent;
    this.setState({username});
  }

  render(){
    return <SomeComponent username={this.state.username} />
  }
}
```